# Sending mail in Zend Framework 2 using Mandrill API

Tags: php, zend-framework2, sendmail, mandrill

I have been trying to set up my Zend Framework environment for sending mails in localhost.I tried to use [Soflomo\Mail](https://github.com/juriansluiman/Soflomo-Mail) for sending email to users who register on my web app using  my RegistrationController and there when index action is called,sendConfirmationMail() function is also called within that.I want to integrate third party email providers like Mandrill with it and [SlmMail](https://github.com/juriansluiman/SlmMail) is a module that integrates with various third-parties API to send mails.I want to set up transactional mail using Mandrill.And I am very much confused.

If anyone has ever integrated Mandrill with Zend Framework 2,Please enlighten me with the example or just guide me on how to setup the complete process.Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/netglue/zf2-mandrill-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So assuming you have this controller action:

```
public function sendAction()
{
    // some logic
    $this->sendConfirmationMail();
}
```

Using Soflomo\Mail and SlmMail, you can link both two the following way.

First, SlmMail provides the transport. There is a Mandrill transport, so follow its [installation instructions](https://github.com/juriansluiman/SlmMail/blob/master/docs/Mandrill.md#installation) first. If you copied the config and set your credentials, you have a service available called `SlmMail\Mail\Transport\MandrillTransport`.

```
private function sendConfirmationMail()
{
    $mail = new \Zend\Mail\Message;

    $transport = $this->getServiceLocator()
                      ->get('SlmMail\Mail\Transport\MandrillTransport');
    $transport->send($mail);
}
```

Obviously, this is not the nicest way. The best is to work with [dependency injection instead of the service locator pattern](https://juriansluiman.nl/article/143/collected-thoughts-about-the-dic-versus-sl-discussion). There is also `Soflomo\Mail` to help with this setup.

Then, you attach the Mandrill transport as the Soflomo\Mail transport. In your config:

```
'service_manager' => [
    'aliases' => [
        'Soflomo\Mail\Transport' => 'SlmMail\Mail\Transport\MandrillTransport',
    ],
],
```

This way, if Soflomo\Mail loads the transport, it loads the transport from SlmMail. Next, Soflomo\Mail provides a facade service which you can load into your controller:

```
use Soflomo\Mail\Service\MailServiceInterface;

class RegistrationController extends AbstractActionController
{
    private $service;

    public function __construct(MailServiceInterface $service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
    }

    public function sendAction()
    {
        // some logic

        $this->sendConfirmationMail();
    }


    private function sendConformationMail()
    {
        $this->service->send([
            /* here all your options*/
        ]);
    }
}
```

The only thing left is to inject the service in the controller. This is quite a standard procedure in ZF2, which I won't explain here. If you need this info, it is perfectly explained in the [ZF2 manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/in-depth-guide/services-and-servicemanager.html#bringing-the-service-into-the-controller). Just remember the service you want to inject is called `Soflomo\Mail\Service\MailService`.

Comment: Thankyou so much !! It was a big help !! Everything works perfectly fine but the mail is not getting sent to new registered user.And I checked my outbound in mandrill and that too is not showing me nothing.Do I need to set any other info of mandrill api apart from api key !!

Comment: Just start to debug: where does the code end? Is it an error somewhere in your own code? Soflomo\Mail? SlmMail? The HTTP client?